# Why can't I change ownership to 'staff' without 'sudo'?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, chown

If I have a file that's owned by `Me` and is in group `staff`, I can `chown Me:admin` and `chown Me:Me` but in order to `chown Me:staff` I must `sudo chown Me:staff` to avoid an "Operation not permitted" error.

Why can't I change ownership to `staff` without `sudo`?

---

I'm running OS X (10.8.2) and in addition to `Me`, `groups` reports `com.apple.access_screensharing everyone _appstore localaccounts admin _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't "give away" files (i.e., change ownership or change group ownership to a group that you don't belong to).

Comment: So if I were a member of staff, I could. That makes sense. But it's odd that the default group for files on OS X one that I (the only user, and admin) am not a member of (by default, I think).